# Jenkins user gets changed based on job name,WHY?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on Linux RHEL7 and i did below changes to run all my Jenkins job with a root user rather than Jenkins user.

The changes I made:

1. Inside file `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`:

   JENKINS_USER="root" (default it used to be "jenkins")
2. Changed the ownership of files using below commands:

   sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/jenkins

   sudo chown -R root:root /var/cache/jenkins

   sudo chown -R root:root /var/log/jenkins

Now when I am creating a job named "snjiii", it runs correctly i.e., using root user:

```
Console Output
Started by user FSQA ADMIN
Running as SYSTEM
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/snjiii
[snjiii] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins8170584152885597665.sh
+ whoami
root
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But when I am creating a different job named as "snjiii_newjob_l1_rhl7", it's running as jenkins user:

```
Console Output
Started by user FSQA ADMIN
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on Slave_1_14 (Redhat_linux) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/snjiii_newjob_l1_rhl7
[snjiii_newjob_l1_rhl7] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins2597327522922634209.sh
+ whoami
jenkins
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I need to create job and run it using root user irrespective of naming convention. How to do it???

Comment: From the output above, you seem to be having a `master-agent/slave` configuration. How did you set up `agent/slave` node?

Comment: I didnt had any master-slave configuration.I was running the jobs directly on my master and was hitting this issue.
But now I have created a node wherein I have created master as slave and ran the job using different naming convention and now its working fine.

Comment: Glad that you've resolved your issue but just out of curiosity, is your master box different from the box which is shown above in the log as `Slave_1_14 (Redhat_linux)`?

Comment: Its the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I was running the job on my master, I created a master-slave configuration for the same wherein I created a node with master credentials and used it as my slave i.e. I restricted my project to run on the slave machine which is my master itself and henceforth it uses ssh credentials to communicate, it resolves my issue.